# Removing empty key from RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am reading a text file and implementing a word count example. The problem is I am getting an RDD with empty Key.

Here is code:

```
val tokens = sc.textFile("test.txt").flatMap(line => line.split(",")).map(_.trim)

val tableForFrequency = tokens.map(word => (word, 1))
  .reduceByKey((a, b) => a + b)

tableForFrequency.saveAsTextFile("file.txt")
```

I am not sure why I am getting an empty and how do I remove it.

Please note: I am a newbie in Scala/Spark and have already looked for related question before posting this one.

Comment: Why wouldn't you? Empty string is still as string....

Comment: So which course is setting this as an assignment? There's been several "newbie in Spark/Scala implementing a word count" questions in the last few days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's consider the following example :

```
val data = Seq("   ","w","w2","")
// data: Seq[String] = List("   ", w, w2, "")

val tokens = sc.parallelize(data).flatMap(line => line.split(",")).map(_.trim)
// tokens: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[9] at map at <console>:29
```

You'll just need to filter out string with length = 0 after triming :

```
val tableForFrequency = tokens.filter(_.length > 0).map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
// tableForFrequency: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = ShuffledRDD[13] at reduceByKey at <console>:31

tableForFrequency.collect
// res4: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((w2,1), (w,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `filter` function can be as complicated or as simple as you need it to be.

In the filter function, just write logic that returns `True` for lines that are not empty and `False` for strings that *are* empty. And also, in terms of strings, `empty` is another way of saying `length == 0`

pseudo-code:

```
.filter( string.length != 0 )
```